# Get next row based on current row and conditional ordering

Tags: sqlite, sqlite-3.33

I have this table:

```
Id   Name
1    M
2    P
3    A1
4    C
5    A2
6    T
1009 A2
1011 A1
1010 A3
```

I can get it sorted by `Id` if `Id < 1000` and by `Name` if `Id > 1000` (thanks to the help of people here) with this query:

```
SELECT *
FROM table1
ORDER BY
  CASE WHEN Id < 1000 THEN Id ELSE 1000 END,
  Name;
```

Which gives

```
Id   Name
1    M
2    P
3    A1
4    C
5    A2
6    T
1009 A2
1010 A3
1011 A1
```

Now, given an `Id`, I want the next row in the order I just ordered by. So far, I've managed to get the result with two SQL queries, based on the `givenId`. If `givenId < 1000` I do:

```
SELECT *
FROM table1
WHERE
  Id > @givenId
ORDER BY
    CASE WHEN Id < 1000 THEN Id ELSE 1000 END,
    Name
LIMIT 1
```

If `givenId > 1000` I do:

```
SELECT *
FROM table1
WHERE
  Id > 1000 AND Name > (SELECT Name FROM table1 WHERE Id = @givenId)
ORDER BY
    CASE WHEN Id < 1000 THEN Id ELSE 1000 END,
    Name
LIMIT 1
```

The `Id` with value 1000 will never exist so I don't have to worry about that case. This works, but I'm wondering if there's a better way to do this? Perhaps with one query instead of two? I've tried to come up with something better but can't seem to.

Comment: Which version of SQLite are you using? Window functions make this easy. But there are other ways to do this too.

Comment: SQLite 3.33.0, I'd prefer my code to be portable so probably want to avoid Windows functions if I can.

Comment: Since 2019 all major DBMSes support this feature, see https://modern-sql.com/caniuse/over_order_by and SQLite got them back in version 3.25

Answer (score 4):

This should get you started:

```
SELECT *
FROM (
  SELECT Id, Name, LEAD(Id) OVER w AS Next_Id, LEAD(Name) OVER w AS Next_Name
  FROM table1
  WINDOW w AS (ORDER BY CASE WHEN Id < 1000 THEN Id ELSE 1000 END, Name)
) WHERE Id = 6;
```

Note that the `order by` is working correctly as it returns `Id = 1011` as the next `Id`.

https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlite_3.27&fiddle=ce891ef6631a142500b59ff2c686e108